# Please Create A Script For Keyword Block

Tags: feature-request, fun, code

If I see another LOST, GLEE, or BIEBER post I'm going to spit nickels. Someone work on a KEYWORD BLOCK, please? We put a man on the moon, we can surely stop the GLEE posts.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: +1 if you actually do spit nickels...show me the video

Comment: Spitting nickels is not that hard. Put nickels in your mouth. Spit nickels out. Done.

Comment: @Jon - The expression **spit nickels** was not preceded by an **@**. Therefore some imagination and poetic license is allowed. My version didn't include sticking nickels in his mouth.

Comment: @dbo - Either you've out sarcasmed me or I've out sarcasmed you. I can't tell which :)

Comment: @Jon - I can agree with that assessment    :)

Answer (score 1):

I only count four Bieber posts. Granted that is still four too many.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bieber

Comment: I think we should send *he who shall remain nameless* a Stack Overflow shirt. Maybe he'll choose a new profession.

Comment: He meant Justin Bieber. I just died a little inside.

Comment: "He who shall not be named" is **Justin Bieber**!?!?!?!?

Comment: O.o  Do you honestly think I would really send him such a prized possession? I suppose I could've used the <sarcasm> tags. Maybe a shirt with a unicorn...

Comment: Who is Justin Bieber!?

Comment: @voyager - *he who shall remain nameless*

Answer (score 0):

I think that a keyword block is completely ridiculous. For instance, let me demonstrate

```
$('#justin-bieber').attr('sucks','true');
```

But if we were to do this what would happen to the code blocks. This would happen

```
FORWARD 100 
LEFT 90
FORWARD 100
LEFT 90
FORWARD 100
LEFT 90
FORWARD 100
LEFT 90
```

Seriously. What were you thinking. We want for Stack Overflow to be more than a pretty square!!

Comment: disclaimer: I do not read or think about what I type.

Comment: (-1) Disclaimers do not excuse adding gibberish to the site.